# Why is Galileo update site empty?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-3.5, galileo, update-site

I just installed Eclipse Galileo for Java developers and noticed that the update site list is empty. Does anyone else have the same problem? I don't know the URL's for the update sites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [this page](http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/eclipse/update-sites/), also [recap on the wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites), you have most of the update sites addresses for Galileo

Regarding the [packaged distro](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) "Java for developers", [bug 249133](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=249133) does report instances of empty list of updates, until an update is performed or one new remote site is entered (then it fills itself again)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the update site is empty at clean install, but when you run an update or install new plugins, the site list will be filled up.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, but it is sure confusing as heck.

Comment: Strangely, it's not working for me even after installing a plugin, and this is the first time I've had this issue with eclipse 3.5.

Answer (score 2):

You may find that by going into the Window -> Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Software there are many update sites that are disabled.  You can highlight them all and click the 'enable' button and then perform your normal updates or exploration for additional plugins.